# not getting float value to crystal report in VS 2019 winform c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

i have changed object format to `-1123.00` but report shows `3.00` instead off `2.6` value saved in SQL server management studio 18 .

[format of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuNEA.png)

[SQL returned row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz4BQ.png)

[result of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bRmz.png)

Comment: How do you get it in SQL before report and post the  format syntax that you set.

Comment: i get it in SQL by executing select query which i also use as view for my report

Comment: what syntax you are asking? i didnt get it

Comment: 1. In view you have: 2.6? 2.format syntax in report viewer

Comment: I mean field format like =Format(Fields!SomeColumn.Value, "0.00")

Comment: sir i didn't set format using code. I now edit the post and attach snapshots

Comment: What the model / dataset do you use to retreive the data?

Comment: unfortunately i don't know the syntax, how to do that because i am new to crystal reports. it will be help full if you guide me :)

Comment: Right click on the field go to format field-->go to number tab -->click on customize-->then in Decimal select "1.0".

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the field go to format field-->go to number tab -->click on customize-->then in Decimal select "1.0".
In addition, SQL statement was modified with cast of field as decimal and problem was resolved.

Comment: What is your regional settings?

Comment: regional setting of what? my laptop is using united state as a region

Comment: Ok, can you give me remote access through TeamViewer or anydesk?

Comment: ok, i have downloaded teamviewer but i dont know how it works :(

Comment: open it and give me the ID and after it temp pass

Comment: id is 1 425 753 957

Comment: and access pass

Comment: password is i9jf54

Comment: Updated the answer after remote connect.